# Can I release an Android App to Google Play Console with Android SDK 29

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm hoping I can release an Android app on Google Play Store next month (August 2021) without having to roll forward my target Android SDK from 29 to 30 as it causes regressions in our app that we don't have time to solve. Google/Android say this:

> **Requirements for new apps**

> From August 2021, the Google Play Console will require all new apps to:
>
> - Publish with the Android App Bundle format.
> - Target API level 30 (Android 11) or above and adjust for behavioural changes.
>
> **Requirements for updates to existing apps**

> From November 2021, updates to existing apps will be required to target API level 30 or above and adjust for behavioural changes in Android 11. Existing apps that are not receiving updates are unaffected and can continue to be downloaded from the Play Store.

So my question is, if I create a release in Google Play Console but don't publish it, i.e - just release it to **Closed Testing**, before August 2021, will our app then be under the category of *existing* apps and be able to remain SDK 20 until November? Or does an app have to be *published* to the public to count as *existing*?

Apologies for the potentially  novice question, but after scouring forums and Google and Android forums and documentation all day, I can't find a clear definition of what *new* and *existing* apps are in their eyes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about app store policies, which are off topic here.

Comment: Yes you can release with API 29 now, if your app exists already on store.but please update existing app to target 30 before November,2021 according to new play policy......but if your app is new first time then you can not release with 29 after 21 agust